# how to set values in anchor form

Tags: codeigniter

I have 3 anchor form in my view. When i click each one it redirects me to the getFeed function in the controller. 
The view:

```
echo anchor('site/getFeed','Tehnology');
echo anchor('site/getFeed','Art');
echo anchor('site/getFeed','Science');
```

Controller:

```
function getFeed($feed_url){
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url)
    $x= new SimpleXmlElement($content);}
```

My question in what to do to assign for each link a $feed_url variable.When i click Technology put in $feed_url a address and calls the getFeed function($feed_url). When click Art $feed_url take another address and put into getFeed function.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo anchor('site/getFeed/some_value','Tehnology');
echo anchor('site/getFeed/another_value','Art');
echo anchor('site/getFeed/some_value_etc','Science');
```

Comment: it gives me an error "string could not be parsed as XML".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a third URL parameter to each of your anchors.  For example

```
echo anchor('site/getFeed/' . $feed_url,'Tehnology');
echo anchor('site/getFeed/' . $feed_url,'Art');
echo anchor('site/getFeed/' . $feed_url,'Science');
```

So the first url parameter `site/` is the name of the controller, `getFeed/` is the name of the function in your controller and then after that any other URL parameters will be passed to your controller function.  You could have more if you wanted

```
echo anchor('site/getFeed/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3','Tehnology');

function getFeed($parameter1, $parameter2, $parameter3) {
    $content = file_get_contents(base_url() . $feed_url);
    try{ 
        $x = new SimpleXMLElement($content); 
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        echo 'Couldn't form XML'; 
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done that but it gives me a error.( String could not be parsed as XML).

Comment: That's because the value in $content isn't XML.  This could be because the file doesn't exist or it doesn't contain XML in it.  So I would check these first.  I've also added an exception to catch any errors

Comment: If i replace in file_get_contents the $feed_url with the address it work. It gives me an error (Message: file_get_contents(http:): failed to open stream: Invalid argument) when i try to put the $feed_url in achor.

Comment: @user3313651 I've updated the code so try again.  Also if you are passing the file_name through the URL you may need to add base_url() before it.  See my updated code

Comment: it gives me the same message :Message: file_get_contents(http://localhost/Codeigniter/http:): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden